# how to used custom widget in yii2 advanced template

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i make simple custom Hellowidget .

HelloWidget class and file put in "components" directory and component directory put in "root directory in application"

`
    public $message;

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    if ($this->message === null) {
        $this->message = 'Hello World';
    }
}

public function run()
{
    return Html::encode($this->message);
}
```

`

when this widget call in views

```
\app\components\HelloWidget::widget(['message' => 'Good morning'])
```

so i am getting error  "Class 'app\components\HelloWidget' not found" namespace add still getting error

any idea about that widget

Answer (score 0):

Hello i found solution

if you work on yii2 advanced template so components can`t put in "root directory" if you put so class not found error get

so solution is if you work on "frontend" so components put in that directory then used custom widget it will works ;)